# Make entire background advertisement clickable

Tags: html, css

I placed a background image (which functions as an advertisement) and I linked it to an extern website. But not the entire images links to it, just a small part of it.

I used an a style:

```
         <div id="bgb" align="center">
<a style="display:block; position:relative; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; cursor:pointer" href="http://www.datura.com/new" alt="datura"><img src="http://taoofsophia.blogandthecity.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/Bg-adv-Datura-3-2.png" style="z-index:-9000"/></a></div>
```

But that doesn't work.. Someone knows how to?

Answer (score 0):

may try this:

```
<div id="bgb" style="margin: 0 auto; position: relative; width: 640px; height: 315.5px">
    <a href="http://www.datura.com/new" alt="datura">
         <img src="http://taoofsophia.blogandthecity.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/Bg-adv-Datura-3-2.png" style="display:block; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; cursor:pointer;"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

You can also try this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Yn53/)

Comment: Thanks Luca, but it didn't work out yet. Is it only possible with the position relative? I guess I need the fixed position to even get the background visible.

Comment: I think maybe it's something in my website that causes it doesn't work the regular way.. My website is http://blogandthecity.net maybe someone sees immediately what's the problem.

Comment: .flex-control-nav li {margin: 0 0 0 5px; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;} Why there is an * before display? And then again, why there is this string: text-shadow: 1px 1px f1f0f0; */ with no commenting effect?